# Get local image path from a widget on Titanium

Tags: javascript, image, titanium, filepath, titanium-widgets

How can I create a widget with its own images to use in any project? I created an "images" folder inside the widget project and now I want to get the path without changing it on every project.

The structure is: `../widgets/WidgetFolderName/images/foo.png`

I tried `WPATH('images/foo.png')` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [Alloy_Widgets](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Widgets) documentation, it searches on the `assets` folder or the `lib` folder.

Create the `assets` folder on the root and move there my `images` folder and leave unchanged the `WPATH` path.